# Signing driver for x64 Windows, making my CA known to Windows - without test-signing

Tags: driver, windows-7-x64, kernel

How can I sign a driver for Windows Vista (and newer) using a certificate rooted in my own CA and make Windows aware that the particular certificate or the CA in which it is rooted is okay to load **without enabling test-signing mode** (`bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON`)?

**Rationale:** enabling test-signing means to enable it *globally* for anything. I don't want that. I want a fine-grained control over what runs. The driver isn't intended for broad use, hence I do not want to open up a huge hole in my security measures by enabling test-signing globally. As far as I'm aware, test-signing basically boils down to a check whether the driver is signed at all (not whether the certificate chain is alright with the Windows kernel).

**Note:** I am aware of the [Kernel-Mode Code Signing Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its pitfalls, I am also aware how to test a driver with test-signing on etc etc, so no need to point these out. In fact I've done those things. All I am really interested in is registering my own certificate or the CA in which it is rooted in order to allow drivers signed with that to run. The local system certificate store (part of the registry, AFAIR), doesn't seem to be available this early in the boot process or doesn't get checked.